# Simple update query caused System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out error in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, code-behind

I'm trying to create a Forgot password page, that verify the user's username, email, security question and answer, before sending them to the new password page. The code below is the onClick that redirect user to the new password page.

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string email = Email.Text;
        string user = UserName.Text;
        string question = Question.Text;
        string answer = Answer.Text;

        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebConfigConString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();

        string strCheck = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ID = @id AND EMAIL = @email AND SECURITYQUESTION = @question AND SECURITYANSWER = @answer";
        SqlCommand cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(strCheck, con);

        cmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", user);
        cmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", question);
        cmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", answer);

        SqlDataReader dtrCheck = cmdCheck.ExecuteReader();

        if (dtrCheck.HasRows)
        {
            Response.Redirect("newPassword.aspx?id=" + user);
        } 
        else
        {
            ErrorMsg.Text = "Invalid username or email / question and answer does not match!";
        }
}
```

And this code below is the form segment of the aspx page for newPassword.

```
<form runat="server">
     <div class="form-group">
         <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">
         Password:</asp:Label>

         <asp:TextBox class="form-control form-control-user" ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
              ErrorMessage="Password is required." ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">
                    Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
         <asp:TextBox class="form-control form-control-user" ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
              ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password"
                                            ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." ForeColor="Red">*</asp:CompareValidator>
     </div>

     <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
     <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Confirm" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"/>
 </form>
```

And this is the codebehind `onclick` function for newPassword:

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        string password = Password.Text;

        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebConfigConString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
        {
            con.Open();

            string strChange = "UPDATE ACCOUNT SET PASSWORD = @password WHERE ID = @id";

            SqlCommand cmdChange = new SqlCommand(strChange, con);

            cmdChange.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmdChange.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

            cmdChange.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            Response.Redirect("login.aspx?msg=Password updated successfully!");
        }
}
```

However, whenever I click submit after filling out the new password, it freeze for a long time then display this error :

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out error

Comment: Why you did not close the connection after executing the command? (First connection for select)

Comment: @MeyssamToluie Yep I'm sorry man I just attempted it and it worked, I didn't done the same on other pages but all of them worked so didn't think of it earlier, thanks and have a good day! And perhaps you could add an answer below for other peoples' reference and I'll accept it

Comment: Don't start new projects in WebForms and .NET Framework, both are dead. Use .NET 6 and ASP.NET Core, using MVC with controllers and views or Razor pages.

Also, don't reinvent the wheel, especially not in the context of security. That is a solved problem, just use ASP.NET Identity. 

Because apparently, one can just navigate to `newPassword.aspx?id=admin` and reset admin's password, and poof, they're admin.

Comment: @CodeCaster A lot of people been telling me the same but it's my college assignment so I got no choice, and thanks a lot for mentioning it, I might change it to CommandArgument together with the button then, have a good day ahead!

Comment: @YUNGFOOKYONG, if you add a `using` block for the first query (like you did for the update), the connection will be closed and disposed automatically. This is a best practice.

Comment: Same goes for the command and reader, they need `using`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I forgot to close the connection before redirecting the user to the newPassword.aspx, simply add a con.Close() before redirecting worked for me.